# Store expanded array in a variable using a brace expansion

Tags: bash, array, brace-expansion

I want to store `node1 node2 node3` in a variable so that it may be used as an input to other scripts.

However, I want to do so by using brace expansion given by bash like so: `node{1..3}`

I tried to have a variable `nodes=node{1..3}`, but when I use it as an argument (`$nodes`) to the script, it gets picked up literally and doesn't expand.

Answer (score 9):

To assign to an array, put the elements in parentheses:

```
nodes=(node{1..3})
```

When using the array, you need to tell bash explicitly that you want to expand it as an array.

```
mycommand "${nodes[@]}"
```

Due to a design quirk of arrays in ksh and bash, `$node` is the first element of the array, you need to explicitly ask for all the elements with the `[@]` indexation. As always, you need [double quotes around the variable expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters); with `[@]`, each element is placed into a separate word.

See the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays) for more information.

`node=node{1..3}` doesn't work because brace expansion only happens in contexts that allow multiple words. An assignment to a scalar (string) variable only allows a single word. You also only get a single word when expanding the variable, since Bash does brace expansion before variable expansion.

Answer (score 0):

To the consideration of expert users:

```bsh
$ mapfile -t arr < <(printf "%s\n" node{1..3})
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
node1
node2
node3
```

[Source](https://ss64.com/bash/mapfile.html)

Comment: It seems slightly awkward to create a file that is then immediately read in again. It would be more straight-forward to assign the elements resulting from the brace-expansion directly to the array with `arr=(node{1..3})`.

Comment: @they yes, that's the answer of Gilles 'SO- stop being evil', I was looking for an alternative. Duly noted.

Answer (score -2):

Found the answer after looking at this question: [What is the rationale behind $array not expanding the whole array in ksh and bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382777/what-is-the-rationale-behind-array-not-expanding-the-whole-array-in-ksh-and-bas?rq=1)

```
nodes=$(echo nodes{1..3})
```

Comment: That sets `nodes` to the string `nodes1 nodes2 nodes3`, not to an array of three elements. This may end up working as desired if node names can't contain whitespace or any of `?*\[` and you use the variable as `$nodes`.